# Refused to execute script from 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.ajax.js' because its MIME type ('image/jpg') is not executable

Tags: javascript, mime

I am developing an application on a platform. In this app I have a `.html` page which calls an external `.js` file.
This is the `header` of my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
```

When I am on Chrome and Opera I have a strange behaviour:

- sometimes I have no problem;
- other times i get this message:`Refused to execute script from 'http://192.168.1.249/ajax.js'
  because its MIME type ('image/jpg') is not executable.`;

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably you have `Content-Type: image/jpg` in response for `ajax.js`

Comment: I have not specify `Content-Type: image/jpg` or any other `Content-Type` anywhere, is this the reason why sometimes I get the desired behaviour?

Comment: Is server, whrer ajax.js is placed under your control? It's server responsibility to serve correct response headers

Comment: The app I am developing is a webserver , I can act on all files involved

Comment: how do you serve static then? Show config, I guess something wrong with it

Comment: I am sorry, I dont understand what you are asking me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84470/discussion-between-sabba-and-andrey).